# RNCryptor Dyld Error Message: Library not loaded

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dyld, xcode6gm

So, I've tired everything to get this to work after I've archived the application, but it keeps failing to open with the error message:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/RNCryptor.framework/Versions/A/RNCryptor
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Project.app/Contents/MacOS/Project
  Reason: image not found
```

I've added the Framework to the Copy Files Build Phase, I've changed the Runpath Search Paths to `@loader_path/../Frameworks` and the Framework Search Path to `@executable_path/../Frameworks` and it still doesn't want to open.

It opens fine in Xcode itself, but as soon as it's archived, it complains and doesn't run.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Try to add RNCryptor.framework to Link Binary With Libraries if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that, but no luck sadly :(

Comment: Target Dependencies? Not an expert in this though.

Comment: So apparently its looking in /Library/Frameworks for the .framework. How do I get Xcode to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to fix it.

So the application was actually looking for the Framework in `/Library/Frameworks/` on my Mac, I originally had thought it was looking for a reference in my actual .app file.

To fix it I opened up Terminal, cd' into the folder containing a copy of RNCryptor.framework and used this command

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/RNCryptor.framework/RNCryptor RNCryptor.framework/RNCryptor
```

Then removed the old framework from the Xcode Project and re-inserted it using the Framework I just used from the directory I cd' into, and added the new Framework to the Copy Files Build Phase.

And voila, it worked :)